# What is the correct Splitting of Audio Stream (ByteArray) in python the 2nd file (2nd chunk) is corrupt

Tags: python, audio, websocket, stream

I did an test implementation to receive an audio stream over an websocket connection
than i buffer and always after 2seconds i would like to save the audio into a file.

For the first chunk that is working well. But for the second and all following chunks the audio files have no sound. I guess its because of the way i am splitting the audio stream into chunks. But I am not sure maybe its something completly different.
Here is the test code i used:

```
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect

from openai import OpenAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
app = FastAPI()


async def transcribe_chunk(audio_chunk, filename: str):
    print("filename:", filename)
    with open('audio_chunk' + filename + '.wav', 'wb') as f:
        print("audio_chunk size:", len(audio_chunk))
        f.write(audio_chunk)


@app.websocket("/audio")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, token: str):
    await websocket.accept()
    audio_buffer = bytearray()
    chunk_size = 16000 * 2  # 2 seconds of audio in bytes
    tasks = []
    i = 0;
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_bytes()
            print("received data")
            audio_buffer += data

            # Check if the buffer has enough data to approximate 2 seconds of audio
            if len(audio_buffer) >= chunk_size:
                print("buffer is full")
                i += 1

                # Slice the buffer to get a 2-second chunk
                audio_chunk = audio_buffer[:chunk_size]
                print(len(audio_chunk))
                # Process the 2-second audio chunk asynchronously

                task = asyncio.create_task(transcribe_chunk(audio_chunk, token + str(i)))
                tasks.append(task)
                audio_buffer = audio_buffer[chunk_size:]

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print("Client disconnected")
        if audio_buffer:
            # Process any remaining audio data
            task = asyncio.create_task(transcribe_chunk(audio_buffer))
            tasks.append(task)

    # Wait for all tasks to complete before ending the function
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution for my own question. But it is not in the python backend and produce a little transfer overhead.

The problem I noticed is caused by the browser which uses webm and not wav for the audio recording.

The solution is simple and a bit stupid, after each chunk i stop and restart the media recorder in frontend now. So it sends complete files and not only chunks of it.